# Post Back a Disabled form inside IFrame from Parent Page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe, postback

I have a page that contains a check box collection, an associated label on the left side, and an Iframe division on the right side.

When the check box division (including label) is clicked, the corresponding page is loaded in Iframe. Also, when clicking on another text check box didvision the page values in the current page should be saved and new page should be loaded in IFrame.

I accomplish this by calling the Javascript function of the Iframe page from parent page which, in turn, does a postback and triggers the save loic inide the event (For eg: I have a button inside each page which is hidden but has an event).

My problem is that when the check box is unchecked, the form displayed on the IFrame is cleared and disabled. So, when I click on some other division the postback of the current disabled form is executed and, since the entire form is disabled, there is no postbacking happening.

How could I trigger Postback for the disabled form or save the data another way?

Note: I even tried enabling the page before calling postback, but it still isn't triggering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to replace your iframes structure with dynamic sections controlled by Ajax.  If this isn't feasible, rethink your disabling of the form.  If the reason you're doing this is to prevent posting values twice, maybe instead of disabling the form, hide the button instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.according to business the form should not be hidden. The entire form should b shown as disabled. I tried enabling the form before calling __dopostback() . But at this time postback doesnt happen . Please help me out

Comment: Are you talking about the update panel in ajax. Will it satisfy all my requirements

Comment: Ajax will allow you to have parts, lets say a div block, that could contain one form, then, on the submit behavior for a button, you could have an ajax call switch out the contents of the div with the new form.  This can also be triggered when a checkbox outside the form is clicked, saving the current form, and loading the new one even if the form inside the tags are disabled.